# Vaex: getValues / rows from a filtered dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, vaex

I am trying to filter a dataframe and get the rows that meet the filter criteria. I have been able to get a the first object from the dataframe by using the `select` function first and then calling the `evaluate` function to get the value:

```
    df.select( (df['mycol1'] == filter_val1) & (df['mycol2'] == filter_val2))
    x_axis_name = df.evaluate(df['x_axis_name'], selection=True).chunk(0)[0]
    x_axis_id = df.evaluate(df['x_axis_id'], selection=True)[0]
    y_axis_id = df.evaluate(df['y_axis_id'], selection=True)[0]
    y_axis_name = df.evaluate(df['y_axis_name'], selection=True).chunk(0)[0]
```

First question: is there a better way to get a row than calling `evaluate` for each column?

Second question: how do I get a list for all of the rows that meet the filter criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit your usecase:

```py
df_filtered = df[(df['mycol1'] == filter_val1) & (df['mycol2'] == filter_val2)]
```

Alternatively, if you need to gradually build an expression you are going to use to filter the dataframe, you can also do:

```py
boolean_expression = df['mycol1'] == filter_val1) & (df['mycol2'] == filter_val2)
df_filtered = df.filter(boolean_expression)
```